# How to copy track in cubase

Tags: midi, cubase

I recently learned alt-dragging sounds in Cubase 5 which is convenient. Is it possible to copy a track even more directly so that the result is that the length doubles? If I start with 4 bars then a want a quick way to double to track to play the same for 8 bars. Currently I do it with alt-dragging but I still must match the correct timing when I paste it, therefore it would be simpler if there was a quick way to double the length including the score.

I only need it for MIDI tracks. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The almighty CTRL + D or CMD + D does just that - duplicates the part. 
I've also found this neat table listing all keyboard shortcuts.

For doubling the tempo you can use the time-stretch cursor on midi, drag it and drop it where is half it's initial size.

[image]